# unknown function called: formatdate - what is equivalent of 'formatdate' in terraform 0.11.x?

Tags: terraform

I want to introduce a simple timestamp to my ec2 instance names

```
   tags = {

    "Name" = "windows server 2012 ${var.env} - ${formatdate("YYYYMMDD", timestamp())}"
}
```

However when I run `terraform validate`,

I got this

```
Error: aws_instance.convertor: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_instance.convertor: 1:33: unknown function called: formatdate in:

 windows server 2012 ${var.env} - ${formatdate("YYYYMMDD", timestamp())}
```

Apparently formatdate is not available in my version of terraform (v0.11.7). How can I achieve the same result in HCL of 0.11.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formatdate function is only available from terraform v0.12. What You can do is use some string manipulation to get your result as explain here ([Terraform timestamp() to numbers only string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54564512/terraform-timestamp-to-numbers-only-string)) and do a simple substring, not a very elegant solution but it works.

```
locals {
 timestamp = "${timestamp()}"
 timestamp_sanitized = "${substr(replace("${local.timestamp}", "/[-| |T|Z|:]/", ""),0,8)}"
}

output "timestamp" {
  value = "${local.timestamp_sanitized}"
}
```